# Javascript color contrast finder

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am trying to create a javascript color contrast finder

```
function gamma_correction(r,g,b) {
    r=calc(r)
    g=calc(g)
    b=calc(b)
    r*=0.2126 
    g*=0.7152
    b*=0.0722 
    
    return r+g+b
}

function hexToRgb(hex) {
    result = /^#?(\[a-f\\d\]{2})(\[a-f\\d\]{2})(\[a-f\\d\]{2})$/i.exec(hex)
    return result ? {
        r:parseInt(result\[1\],16),
        g:parseInt(result\[2\],16),
        b:parseInt(result\[3\],16)
    } : null;
}

function calc(c) {
    let t = 0.03938;
    c/=255;
    return (c < t)? c /= 12.92: c = (((c + .055) / 1.055) ^ 2.4);
}

let x=document.getElementById('colorpicker')
x.addEventListener('change',()=\>{
    var {r,g,b} =hexToRgb(x.value)
    return document.getElementById('L1').innerText=gamma_correction(this.r,this.g,this.b)        
});

let y =document.getElementById('colorpicker2')
y.addEventListener('change',()=\>{
    var {r,g,b} =hexToRgb(y.value)
    return document.getElementById('L2').innerText=gamma_correction(this.r,this.g,this.b)   
});
```

Comment: You did not ask any questions.

Comment: This line looks a bit suspicious: `return (c < t)? c /= 12.92: c = (((c + .055) / 1.055) ^ 2.4);` Are you using the `^` operator as power? It is the XOR operator.